# What will be the solution if my api key is valid and appropriate but android studio still showing error please pass valid api key in flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

E/flutter (10591): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.

Comment: Hi Sunirban,  You might need use a debugger to see more details about the cause of this exception.  API keys are usually used when contacting a remote server, such as when making a REST call.  If you debug step into the code that sends the API key, then you can see if the key is correct.  * Another idea is to change your log level to DEBUG.  You might see a more detailed, helpful error message.   Good luck!